# Error in uploading DLL in Tridion using post build event in Visual Studio

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to upload an assembly in Tridion Content Manager through the following post build event of a project in Visual Studio:
  C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\\\bin\Debug\name of dll

Config.xml has been created through cmd as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<templateAssemblyUploadConfig>
  <targetURL>http://<url>/</targetURL>
  <userName>domain\user id</username>
  <password>password</password>
  <uploadPDB>false</uploadPDB>
</templateAssemblyUploadConfig>
```

When I try to build the DLL , it is giving the following error.

Error 1: Unexpected argument: Unexpected argument Studio C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\\\bin\Debug\name of dll\EXEC name of DLL

Error 2: The command "  C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\\\bin\Debug\name of dll" exited with code 1. name of DLL

Can someone help in solving the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you use 'Space' and not the 'Enter' button in between the command.

Comment: Thanks All...We were using "Enter" instead of "Space". Now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Great to see the help by Huston.
you may also try a visual Studio Add-In which allows to upload dll(s) into Tridion in a more easy way
http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/AssemblyUploader2.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is my post-build event:

```
E:\Tridion\bin\client\TcmUploadAssembly.exe  e:\Tridion\bin\client\config.xml "$(TargetPath)" /folder:tcm:43-61362-2
```

Comment: If the path to your project contains spaces you should put the path to the assembly (and/or the path to the config.xml) in double quotes as well.